# CORS dosent work when GET request is encoded

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, security, cors

I have a Spring boot application that provides some REST endpoints.

One is a GET reques endpoint  : "APIURL/client/search/{keyword}" . It filters from all existing clients in DB those who have that word in their name-description-country etc.

An application for the frontend part is using NodeJS and PrimeReact.
It will call that search API with

```
search = (filter) => {
        const queryString = filter;
        if (queryString) {
            fetch(`${API_URL}/client/search/${queryString}`)
```

I found a small bug: if I search with a word containing "/" it will fail cause the call will try "search/word/afterSlash" and responde with "404 Not Found".
Now I will encode the word

```
let encodedQuery = encodeURIcomponent(query);
```

Now any special word is encoded BUT CORS filer fails for words like "C/C++" but works for "C++".  It says " No
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" present in response"
BUT in my Java server I have

```
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

And any other API works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not encode url parts ... you have to transform queryString to a request param ( and encode it )

```
${API_URL}/client/search?query=${encodedQueryString}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I mearly forgot that you can call either by search/USA or search?country=USA. I can not test it right now but im very sure this will work! Thank you so much

Comment: I will return to this question if there are any more issues and of course to accept your answer as the correct one.